# Create a string from characters that contain both single and double quotes?

Tags: r

Is there a way to create a string from some text that contains both single `'` and double `"` quote characters?

#### Example

Suppose we some text containing both single and double quotes (presume an actual use case would be much longer):

```
Here's a message: "hello, world!"
```

Wrapping it in `'`, or `"` doesn't work:

```
thing <- "Here's a message: "hello, world!""
Error: unexpected symbol in "thing <- "Here's a message: "hello"

thing <- 'Here's a message: "hello, world!"'
Error: unexpected symbol in "thing <- 'Here's"
```

I can think of two ways that would probably work. 1. Dump the text into RStudio (or a text editor) and find and replace. 2. Paste into a text file and read in the lines with `readLines()`. I just wanted to see if there's an easier way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have a version 4.0.0 or later R, you can use `r"(all of your text here)"`.

```r
text <- r"(My text "has" double and 'single' quotes)"

> cat(text)
My text "has" double and 'single' quotes
```

Documentation for this can be found by running `help("Quotes")`.

Comment: I forgot they added that recently - that's a great solution and definitely what @stevec wants imo

Comment: Can you help me find the documentation on this? I tried some variants of `?r"(` but couldnt pull up anything

Comment: @LiefEsbenshade I edited with how to get to the help file for this topic. It is a bit buried, but is there. The paragraph starts with "Raw character constants..."

Comment: Thanks! I see it now. There's helpful info there about how to adjust the opening/closing sequences using `{` `[` and `-` that may be useful for others trying to copy code from other languages into R.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to make this work with multiple lines? I've tried on something like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/QCTfDgcf/image.png) (same as your example just with a few new lines added), and I can't get it working with `r"( ... )"` nor any of the other methods mentioned under `help("Quotes")`. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually, it's something to do with my RStudio configuration, as the `r"( ... )"` method works fine on multiple lines when running from R in the terminal, rather than RStudio. Weird!

Answer (score 2):

If you're inputting directly into the console then you'll just want to escape the quotes using a backslash.  Here's an example:

```
> text <- "Here\'s a message: \"hello, world!\""
> cat(text, "\n") # Adding a new line so the prompt doesn't mess things up
Here's a message: "hello, world!"
```

Comment: The problem is when the text is large, the manual escaping becomes very onerous. I wonder if there's any way to emulate the effect of ' and " without using either of those characters. That way, it would just be a matter of adding a character (or some symbol) at the very start and very end of the text. (+1 for the help)

Comment: Are you reading in from a file? If so there are ways to deal with it. If you're pasting directly in there isn't much to be done since you're dealing directly with the interpreter.

Comment: Actual use case right now is copying (extremely long) curl commands. They contain all sorts of characters, but they work wonderfully in the mac terminal. I want to quickly run them from R with something like `system()`, but I have had the same problem before, I always found clunky work arounds. Very often when copying HTML from a website into R for analysis (very particular HTML, not available via rvest/selenium)

Comment: stevec Gotcha. @Adam just provided a solution that I think is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply escape the characters using backslash "":

```
thing <- "Here's a message: \"hello, world!\""
```

now you can print the variable using cat:

```
cat(thing)
```

don't worry if the R console shows the backslash characters, because they not actually part of the string

```
> xx <- "\""
> xx
[1] "\""

> length(xx)
[1] 1 # you see it is just one character! :)
```